# R! mutate conditional and list intersect (How many time was a player on the court ?)

Tags: r

This is a sport analysis question - How many time was a player on the court ?

I have a list of players I am interested in

`names <- c('John','Bill',Peter')`

and a list of actions during multiple matches

```
team    <- c('teama','teama','teama','teama','teama','teama','teamb','teamb')
player1 <- c('John', 'John', 'John', 'Bill', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Steve', 'Steve')
player2 <- c('Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'John', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Peter', 'Bob')
df <- data.frame(team,player1,player2)
```

I want to build a column that will list how many action was the player on the court

```
actions_when_player_on_court <- df %>% group_by(team) %>% 
calculate({nb of observation where the player is either player1 or player2} )
```

so I end up with a new list like

```
actions_when_player_on_court <- c(4,3,1)
```

so I can create a new DF like this

```
new df <- data.frame(names,actions_when_player_on_court)
```

where John appears 4 times on the court, Bill twice, and Peter once

I feel I may need to intersect the names and c(player1,player2) especially if

- names are unique - John, Bill and Peter cannot belong to other teams and are unique in df
- I may have 0 to n players on the field so 0 to n column (player1, player2... playern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do what you need.

We first need to create a new data frame to store all names and an empty *actions_when_player_on_court* variable.

```
names = c()
for (i in 2:ncol(df)) {
    names = c(names, unique(df[,i]))
}
names = data.frame(name = unique(names), actions_when_player_on_court = 0)
```

Then, we can fill the *actions_when_player_on_court* variable using a for loop:

```
df$n = 1
for (i in 2:(ncol(df)-1)) {
    tmp = aggregate(cbind(n = n) ~ df[, i], data = df[, c(i, ncol(df))], FUN="sum")
    names(tmp)[1] = "name"
    names = merge(names, tmp, all=T)
    names[is.na(names)] = 0
    names$actions_when_player_on_court = names$actions_when_player_on_court + names$n
    names = names[-ncol(names)]
}
```

You can have as many players as you want as long as they start with the second column an run until the end of the data frame. Note that the resulting data frame does not include the *team* variable. I think you can deal with that yourself. Here is the result:

```
> names
   name actions_when_player_on_court
1  Bill                            3
2   Bob                            1
3  John                            4
4  Mike                            5
5 Peter                            1
6 Steve                            2
```